Movie begins (almost) with boy and girl faking car accidents to rob helpers
Released around 2002, about two juvenile delinquents, boy and girl. At the beginning of the movie, they fake car accidents and ask drivers for help, then they steal their car (or something like that). One of the drivers outsmarts them and then hires them, partially under threat of legal consequences. He is from some criminal organization; a lawyer, if I remember correctly.
He gives them high-risk criminal tasks, including planting a bomb in a shop (the owner of which refused to sell his property, thus standing in the way of some ambitious project) and (unintentionally) killing some "uncooperative" city council member (a last obstacle to above-mentioned project) in suspenseful scene on the beach involving attempted rape and self defense murder (stone wound to the head); the plot was to create a public image threat (blackmail).

Sounds like The Learning Curve from 2001 about Paul and Georgia, a couple of young grifters who perform scams together. And then:

When they try to scam Marshal (played by Vincent Ventresca) by staging a road accident using Georgia as a distracting female hitchhiker it seems that they have struck a very dangerous individual as he produces a gun and kidnaps them.
Marshal is head of a record company and controls a very large financial empire and he takes Paul and Georgia to his offices where he eventually makes them an offer and congratulates them for their enterprise. 

Marshal wants to take over a mall but the zoning committee is standing in his way, so he hires Paul and Georgia to do the dirty work for him. Here's the trailer:



